# Download Attachment from outlook using Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am using below code to download the attachment from email based on subject, but i am unbale to use like operater to check the subject and download, below is the code which i am using

I was tring for  [Subject] like Test Powershell, but i am unable to achive this

**

```
$filepath = “D:\PowerShell”
 $filter="[Subject]=Test Powershell"
 $myNow = get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss"
 Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
 $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]  
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application 
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
 $namespace.Logon("profilename","mypassword",$false,$false)
 $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox)
#$folder.items|select *
$folder.items.Restrict($filter) |
  select -Expand Attachments | % {
    for ($i = $_.Count; $i; $i--) {
      $_.Item($i).SaveAsFile("$filepath\$($_.Item($i).FileName)")
    }
  }
```

**

Answer (score 0):

When matching string properties, you can use either a pair of single quotes ('), or a pair of double quotes ("), to delimit a string that is part of the filter.

In specifying a filter in a Jet or DASL query, if you use a pair of single quotes to delimit a string that is part of the filter, and the string contains another single quote or apostrophe, then add a single quote as an escape character before the single quote or apostrophe. Use a similar approach if you use a pair of double quotes to delimit a string. If the string contains a double quote, then add a double quote as an escape character before the double quote.

For example, in the DASL filter string that filters for the `Subject` property being equal to the words `Test Powershell`, the entire filter string is delimited by a pair of double quotes, and the embedded string `Test Powershell` is delimited by a pair of single quotes. There are three characters that you need to escape in this filter string: the starting double quote and the ending double quote for the property reference of `https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f`, and the apostrophe in the value condition for the words `Test Powershell`.

```
$filter = "@SQL=""https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f"" = 'Test Powershell'"
```

or

```
$filter = "@SQL=""https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f"" like '%Test Powershell%'"
```